# Azure policies(gatekeeper) monitoring on AKS via Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: azure, prometheus, grafana, azure-aks, azure-policy

I have enabled azure policies via terraform and applied to AKS cluster. I can see pods are deployed, up and running. I applied in-built initiative [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policySetDefinitions/Kubernetes/Kubernetes_PSPBaselineStandard.json) too with effect "audit" to test out how azure policies works on aks cluster.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n gatekeeper-system
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
gatekeeper-audit-77754c7d8-g44qb        1/1     Running   0          44h
gatekeeper-controller-78cff9c89-7pftn   1/1     Running   0          44h
gatekeeper-controller-78cff9c89-8dsfg   1/1     Running   0          44h
```

I found a dashboard https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/15763

But some of the metrics are different/missing. Not sure, because, azure managing this gatekeeper!?. I see below some panel are displaying and metrics are available in prometheus. For example below `opa_scorecard_constraint_violations` not avilable.
[image]

How to monitor azure policies via prometheus properly

Comment: From official website https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/metrics also they have not mentioned metrics start with `opa_` or `opa_scorecard_constraint_violations`

Comment: asked https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/issues/2070

Answer (score 0):

I don't think metrics like `opa_scorecard_constraint_violations` can be exported when you're using `Azure Policies(+Gatekeeper)`

However you can export gatekeeper metrics, you just need to create a service monitor to hit the proper endpoint.

My service monitor looks like this:

```html
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    monitoring: prometheus
  name: gatekeeper-system-pod-monitor
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  jobLabel: gatekeeper.sh/system
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - gatekeeper-system
  podMetricsEndpoints:
  - honorLabels: true
    path: /metrics
    port: metrics
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      gatekeeper.sh/system: "yes"
```

grafana screenshot:
[metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOZmW.png)